# img tag on wordpress page has sudden error appear on live site, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in front-page.php

Tags: wordpress

sudden WordPress error appeared on my live site, I didn't update anything, not sure why I'm getting this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in front-page.php on line 23

This is what line 23 has, which was working for a couple of months.

```
<img class="blogPostImg" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url('get_the_ID'(),'full') ?>" />
```

Does anyone know how to fix this and/or why this error suddenly appeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this stopped working, but I found code that fixed it.

```
<img class="blogPostImg" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null,'full') ?>" />
```

Comment: Just so you know what the problem was: you had `'get_the_ID'()` when it should have been `get_the_ID()` (notice the lack of single quotes) instead.

Comment: That makes sense. It's really weird that it worked for weeks and then stopped working even with the error.